# alleviating localised pressure from pedal cage

Tags: pedals, health

I ride my Brompton in normal shoes with quill/cage pedals and half-clips:
[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

---

I've done 25-100 miles journeys, and occasionally find the balls of my feet get sore / toes go a bit numb. It feels as though it occurs where there is localised pressure from the leading edge of the cage. My guess is that the sole of my shoe does not distribute pressure enough (although from other questions here, perhaps I have a circulation issue too).

I see that rigid insoles exist for medical conditions. Would inserting one (or just a metal/plastic sheet of some sort) under a normal insole spread the pressure out at all? Would heat-moldable insoles do anything useful?

Would switching to platform pedals be likely to make any difference?
I need removable pedals, so something like MKS Allways, say:

[image]

Or, going really DIY, the Esprit cage is bolted on, how about mounting a strip of aluminium L profile over the leading edge to increase its surface area?

Comment: Turns out (a) using Endura Humvee flat pedal shoes, or (b) not using toeclips (I guess foot position changes slightly) alleviates the symptoms. But I prefer half-clips in the wet, so shall next try adding a spacer to the half-clips, May convert this to an answer if it works out.

Comment: Another thought is to try a pair of shoes with thicker soles to spread the pressure, or some orthotic-type inserts to cushion more of the foot.

Answer (score 2):

Addressing a couple of your points:

- If you wanted to stiffen the sole, you'd need to add quite a lot of stiffness to some shoes; in others, adding padding might help:

  - The left pair (black casual trainers) are probably a bit soft and might benefit from stiffening.  I'd use 1 or 1.5mm polycarbonate sheet, and cut it with a jigsaw, clamping 2 sheets between 2 boards of scrapwood and cutting both feet at once.
  - The Oxfords on the right may already have quite a stiff sole, but they often have a thin sole.  A thick gel insole might be all you need, assuming you have room for it.
- Screwing extra aluminium onto the back edge might help, but you'd have to watch for the effect on the balance of the pedal - adding too much mass will alter the way it tilts and make it harder to get you toes into the clip.

But pedals with a cage of bent sheet metal (like those Esprit) are about the worst for concentrating pressure.  They grip most soles well, but almost anything else would be better.

If you're into DIY solutions, a pair of aluminium sheets per pedal could be used to fill in the middle - choose a thickness so the cage is just proud of the sheet, and countersink the screws into the top - your toe clips clearly define a top and bottom so (self-locking) nuts on the underside wouldn't be a problem.  I'd probably use chequer plate (checker/tread plate) to provide some grip.  Offcuts and small sheets are cheap on eBay.

Comment: If you're keen on the DIY idea and I wasn't clear enough, I can sketch something out

Comment: The left pair are actailly cycling-specific shoes ([Leatt 1.0](https://fe.staging.leatt.com/us/product/1-0-shoes-flat)) and supposedly already have a "stiffened insert for pedal support"

Comment: Then it's definitely the cage that's the problem

Comment: I just had another thought. I have biggish feet (~UK11). If I add spacers to extend the toe-clip, the ball of my foot would be between the cage edges, rather than directly over one, which might also help.

Comment: That's easy enough to test with a couple of nuts as spacers and longer bolts.  But it just moves the pressure point, which may or may not be enough

Comment: The chequer plate idea is interesting. The Esprit cage is bolted on, so I could probably just replace it entirely if I can fabricate a suitable alternative platform. Being single-sided, it might even work out slightly lighter (and my brompton already weighs 16kg!). Think I'll experiment with insoles and extending the toe-clip first, though, as that's easier.

Comment: A decent bench vice and some wood and clamps will allow reasonably accurate bending of 2mm plate in that width, so it's really quite easy.  I've done plenty of sheet-aluminium DIY, though little of it for bike stuff

Comment: Just realised while fixing image linkrot that I mistakenly had "trailing edge" when I meant "leading edge" (the edge under the ball of the foot. Oops. So point 2 re balance would probably not be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

The pin pedal pictured will help, providing more surface area than the edge of metal one.

Without making a specific product recommendation, do look about for pedals with a different shape of platform that may suit you more.

[image] 
 the MKS Lambda pedal offers length.  The Gamma is similar.

[image] 
 the MKS GR-10 platform.

Be aware that some of the odd-shaped pedals may not take a toe retainer (cage/basket)

---

Most of these will be for normal thread-in crank arms.  You want quick-plug axles, which some manufacturers offer, but another option is to look at adapters.  You're not limited to Brompton compatible pedals using an adapter like this:

[image] 
 all over aliexpress and similar sources.

Comment: My Esprit use MKS's "EZY Superior" QR system. I think pedals like the ones in your picture usually copy the older EZY system and need an easily-lost plastic clip to be secure. The [Urban Platform EZY Superior](https://www.mkspedal.com/?q=en/product/node/56) seem to be the QR equivalent of the GR10 and look like they could be a good option. They take(need) toe clips but fitting rear-facing reflectors looks a bit tricky. More importantly, they don't seem available here in UK. Boo.

Comment: @jhnc yep - I'm trying to avoid specific product recommendations, and simply using the ones above to illustrate what might work better for you.  The adapters were to show you're not stuck with brompton specific, that alternatives are available, but I'm not familiar with Bromptoms specifically.

Comment: @jhnc an alternative to reflectors is the stick-on tape that is DOT reflective.  I've put patches of it on the back of seatposts, seat-stays, and on full mudguards and it works well as a reflector.  I guess you could put some on the rear-face of each crank too

Comment: @jhnc (I'm also in the UK) most clipless pedals lack reflectors (or they theoretically exist but they're not imported and anyway fall off easily).  So while supposedly required it's not a big deal.  I've added retroreflective tape to some of my pedals and a pair of  bike-specific shoes (3M brand sticks better than the cheaper stuff I've had).  It wouldn't work so well on all pedals.  I might take up Criggie's idea of putting a little on the cranks as well.

Comment: BTW there are also retroreflective paints.  A sample size container would be enough for a pair of pedals

Comment: @ChrisH Thanks, I prefer actual BS6102/2 reflectors (I was amazed at the outright lies a driver told to avoid taking responsibility for sending my friend to hospital with a broken spine, so minimising scope for (arguably legitimate) claims of contributory negligence should ever one hit me seems prudent).

Comment: @jhnc understandable, but very limiting.  Anyway you could be head to toe in standards compliant lights and reflectors and a  driver hitting you would still have a high chance of getting off very lightly, so I've given up. BTW I first came across these lies decades ago (not me, my brother, on a motorbike, lying van driver)

Comment: In the end I did put retro-reflective tape on a pair of cranks, with clipless pedals that left next to no surface area for reflective material. The curve of the ends wasn't really big enough, so I put some on both faces that can face the front/rear. It still had to be a very narrow strip. So a useful addition rather than a complete solution. I used the dark grey that reflects white, and also have orange reflective tape on my cycling shoes

Answer (score 1):

In general, I get Plantar fasciitis.  Since wearing MTB shoes and MTB pedals on my road bike, I get a lot less pain.

The stiffness of a MTB soles and grippy shoe sole compound means I can get more support on my feet while riding and still walk with them to a change room where I can then replace my footwear to suite the day.

Also I have replaced my cheap pedals with MTB pedals and I've put half-toe clips.  I had to improvise with with the toe clips, I bought MKS metal half-toe clips and then snap-off the angled bracket and drill wholes on the clips and one hole on the pedal to hold the clips in place.

Here are some photos of what I needed to purchase to finished product.
Also photos of my MTB shoes, pedals and half toe clips assembled.

I hope this helps any one with similar feet problems.  Regards

[image: SHIMANO SH-GR701 FLAT PEDAL SHOES BLACK]

[image: Bike Pedals 9/16 Inch]

[image: MKS (Migashima) Half Clip Steel Deep with Leather]

[image: List of tools for half-toe clips in MTB pedals]

[image: Half-toe clip underside]

[image: Comparison old with new pedals]

[image: New pedals in crank]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiRik.jpg)
[image]